# Selenium - Drag and Drop

Tags: python, selenium, drag-and-drop

I am looking to automate the dropping of a file from the desktop to the page using Firefox as the browser, and Selenium on Python for automation.

Here is the code for the drag-and-drop on the page:

```
<div id="dropbox">...</div>
<script type="text/javascript"> ... 
   dropbox.addEventListener("drop", dropUpload, false);
<script>

...

function dropUpload(event) { 
... 
files = event.dataTransfer.files;
...
}
```

Most of the threads out there deal with dropping some other element besides a file from the filesystem. The problem is that I need the event to contain a file object with the actual data.

I've tried just typing into the dropbox element, as others have suggested, but this obviously doesn't work with a div element.

Answer (score 0):

This is very painful to do with Selenium alone. If using a commercial add-on to Selenium is an option for you, you can try [Helium](http://heliumhq.com). It lets you drag your file via the following code:

```
from helium.api import drag_file
drag_file(r"C:\Documents\notes.txt", to=driver.find_element_by_id("dropbox"))
```

Nicer still is if your `#dropbox` div contains some text, eg. `Drop files here`. Then you can do

```
drag_file(r"C:\Documents\notes.txt", to="Drop files here")
```